# Stand alone ".exe" matlab file not saving images

Tags: c#, matlab

I'm trying to create an ".exe" file that will read some sort of data(for a known path), and will plot it one time as "bplot" and the other time as "histogram".

The code works fine as I run it from the editor, and even after I've made an ".exe" file. The problem begins when I try to run it from a "C#" code with the command "Process.Start(@"my_path.exe")". It seems like it runs the code and I can see the figures that are made, but it doesn't save the pictures.

My matlab code is:

```
clear
clc
P = csvread('my_path\test_csv.csv');
SP = bplot(P);
pause (3);
saveas(figure(1),[pwd '\picture1.jpeg']);
pause (3)
B = csvread('my_path\test2_csv.csv');
histogram(B);
pause (3)
saveas(figure(1),[pwd '\picture2.jpeg']);
pause (3)
close
clear
clc
```

The "bplot" is an external function that I downloaded. 
Any ideas how to save it in other way so the stand alone application will save the images when I call it from C# code?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the syntax with `ProcessStartInfo` parameter (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/0w4h05yb(v=vs.110).aspx)), rather than syntax with the path the file directly.

Indeed if not setting `ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory`, it will be considered to be `%SYSTEMROOT%\System32` (for which you don't have write access as normal user)

```
 var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"my_path.exe");
 startInfo.WorkingDirectory= .... you exe dir or something else....;

 Process.Start(startInfo);
```